# How to work with Bubble Sort to determine highest number [C++]

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

My assignment is to create a function determine the highest number of a given array read from a text file. I've looked into using bubble sorting and I think that since the assignment does not ask for sorted numbers, it is unnecessary to store them as such

Here is what I've got so far

```
void determineWinner(string namesArr[], float votesArr[], int size)
{
    int temp = 0;
    string tempname;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (votesArr[i] > votesArr[i + 1])
        {
            temp = votesArr[i];
            tempname = namesArr[i];
            votesArr[i] = votesArr[i + 1];
            namesArr[i] = namesArr[i + 1];
            votesArr[i + 1] = temp;
            namesArr[i + 1] = tempname;
        }
    }
}
```

I've created it such that it tests the condition, (with the goal in mind to sort smallest to biggest), and then replaces i with i+1. And then because the "votes" are linked to specific names, I switch the names as the votes move around.

For instance the array would be arranged at first

```
5000, 4000, 6000, 2500, 1800
```

and would need to end up as

```
1800, 2500, 4000, 5000, 6000
```

I think I'm getting a runtime error with "program name has stopped working", what can I do to fix this up?

Comment: As this is an assignment I won't give a direct answer, but look into storing the file contents (if not too large) into a `std::vector` and using `std::max_element` to find maximum value.

Comment: `max = -some_big_number; for each element in array { if (element > max) max = element }`

Comment: Please study how to use your debugger. The crash reason is most likely because you are accessing one past the end of the array - you should loop until `size - 1`. However, your code doesn't solve your problem, insertion sort is always better than bubble sort, and you don't need to sort the array anyway.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: That vector sounds redundant. `max_element` just requires a forward iterator, and `istream_iterator` can read directly from file.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that the size of your array is 5, means it contains the elements 0,1,...,4 which you want to iterate from `i=0` to `i<5`.

This means that in the 4th run, you will try `if (votesArr[4] > votesArr[4+1])`, which is not legal, as the 4th element is the last (there is no 5th).

So either you start at `i=1` and do something like `if (votesArr[i-1] > votesArr[i])` or you only go to `i < size-1`.

Think about when you only have two elements. You would only need one comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try to look after your bubble sort algorithm, it doesn't seem correct to me.

If you only want the highest element, you should keep the actual highest in memory (your temp variable) and overwrite it every time, you find a bigger one.